# Django model: Reference foreign key table in __unicode__ function for admin

Tags: python, django, admin

Example models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.parent.name # Would reference name above
```

I'm wanting the Child.**unicode** to refer to Parent.name, mostly for the admin section so I don't end up with "Child object" or similar, I'd prefer to display it more like "Child of ". Is this possible? Most of what I've tried hasn't worked unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return u'Child of %s' % unicode(self.parent)
```

Obviously you've defined a `__unicode__()` method in the parent that makes sense, right?

Comment: Oh fffffff I see. That works, thanks.

Apparently my __unicode__ method wasn't working right (?), I used __str__ and THAT showed up in the admin. Any idea why that is? I thought Django would call __unicode__ by default?

Comment: `{{ obj }}` in a template calls `unicode(obj)`. Everything else is left to Python.